# how to find the total

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table A and the output expected is below.

Table A

```
Id  patientId   PID
1   123         p1    
1   123         p2    
1   124         p3    
1   124         p4    
1   125         p5    
2   126         p6    
2   126         p7    
2   126         p8    
2   127         p9    
2   127         p10
```

Count of pid is the count for every patientId how many pids are present and Total count of IDs is the total number of Ids(lets say 5 for Id 1 for example) 
Expecting an output like this:

```
id  patientId   Count of pid    Total count of IDs
1   123                 2          5    
1   124                 2          5    
1   125                 1          5    
2   126                 3          5    
2   127                 2          5
```

I am not sure how to go beyond this

```
select Id,patientId,count(PID)    
from A     
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.Id,a.patientId,count(a.patientId), a2.IdCount
from A a
left join (select Id, count(Id) as "IdCount"
            from A
            group by Id) a2
        on a.Id = a2.Id
group by a.Id,a.patientId, a2.IdCount
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to count over two different fields, you need two separate `GROUP BY` subqueries, which can be `JOIN`ed on `Id`:

```
SELECT A1."Id",
       A1."patientId",
       A1.num_pids,
       A2.total_ids
FROM (SELECT "Id", "patientId", COUNT(*) AS num_pids
      FROM A
      GROUP BY "Id", "patientId") A1
JOIN (SELECT "Id", COUNT(*) AS total_ids
      FROM A
      GROUP BY "Id") A2 ON A2."Id" = A1."Id"
ORDER BY "Id", "patientId"
```

Output:

```
Id  patientId   num_pids    total_ids
1   123         2           5
1   124         2           5
1   125         1           5
2   126         3           5
2   127         2           5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a window function:

```
select Id, patientId, count(*),
       count(*) over ()   
from A     
group by 1, 2;
```

The second `count(*)` counts the number of rows in the result set, which appears to be what you want.